# Xmonad terminal creates three processes

Tags: linux, desktop, xmonad

I'm configuring xmonad. I changed the terminal to `terminal="urxvt"` but I don't like that it spawn three processes per each terminal I open:

```
~$ ps -fea --forest
fake 16042 12136  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00          \_ /bin/sh -c urxvt
fake 16043 16042  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00          |   \_ urxvt
fake 16044 16043  0 11:22 pts/2    00:00:00          |       \_ bash
```

How can I fix that? Can I remove the `/bin/sh -c urxvt` process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally XMonad uses [`spawn` in XMonad.Core](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Core.html):

> `spawn :: MonadIO m => String -> m ()`
>
> spawn. Launch an external application. Specifically, it double-forks and runs the String you pass as a command to `/bin/sh`.

So if one wants to only change the `terminal` value, rather than using say `executeFile` directly, one would have to use `exec` in the shell command, `terminal="exec urxvt"`, which would remove the extra `/bin/sh` by causing it to `exec` the command rather than the shell being the process's parent.